# how to use several collection_select boxes that are pulling from the same model?

Tags: ruby, html, css, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building out a CAD app in Rails 4 and Ruby 2.2.

The snag I have hit is as follows:

I am attempting to use collection_select (Dynamic Select Boxes) to pull Users employee_ident numbers into several "responding units" lines. Some will be used some wont always be used.

I have listed out in my index , form and edit pages 4 lines that are all relatively exact. they all refrence the user_id..

the problem I am finding is that when I select the unit for unit_1, then units 2 3 and 4 all pull over the user_id of the user I put in the first box..

here is the HTML and ERB for the entire panel in question:

```
<div class="panel panel-success" id="responding-box">
  <div class="panel-heading"><center><h4>Units Responding</h4></center></div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><center>Unit #1</center></th>
        <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
        <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><center><%= collection_select(:call, :unit_1, User.all, :id, :employee_ident, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %></center></td>
        <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit_on_scene %></center></td>
        <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit_clear %></center></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><center>Unit #2</center></th>
        <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
        <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><center><%= collection_select(:call, :unit_2, User.all, :id, :employee_ident, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %></center></td> 
        <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit2_os %></center></td>
        <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit2_cl %></center></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><center>Unit #3</center></th>
        <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
        <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><center><%= collection_select(:call, :unit_3, User.all, :id, :employee_ident, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %></center></td> 
        <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit3_os %></center></td>
        <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit3_cl %></center></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><center>Unit #4</center></th>
        <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
        <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td><center><%= collection_select(:call, :unit_4, User.all, :id, :employee_ident, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %></center></td> 
        <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit4_os %></center></td>
        <td><center><%= f.time_select :unit4_cl %></center></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I put back the unit_1 through unit_4 so you can see what I am trying to do, but originally I had

```
<td><center><%= collection_select(:call, :user_id, User.all, :id, :employee_ident, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %></center></td>
```

but with unit_1 through 4 even if I set it an an integer it still doesn't pull when I try to connect it like this:

```
<%= @call.user.employee_ident %>
```

**My current Controller Looks Like:**

```
class CallsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_call, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /calls
  # GET /calls.json
  def index
    @calls = Call.all
    @active_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == 'ACTIVE'}
    @pending_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == 'PENDING'}
  end

  # GET /calls/1
  # GET /calls/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /calls/new
  def new
    @call = Call.new
  end

  # GET /calls/1/edit
  def edit
    @call = Call.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /calls
  # POST /calls.json
  def create
    @call = Call.new(call_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.save
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Call was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @call }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /calls/1
  # PATCH/PUT /calls/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.update(call_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Call was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @call }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /calls/1
  # DELETE /calls/1.json
  def destroy
    @call.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to calls_url, notice: 'Call was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_call
      @call = Call.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def call_params
      params.require(:call).permit(:call_time, :status, :primary_type, :secondary_type, :site, :address, :unit_1, :unit_2, :unit_3, :unit_4, :call_details, :unit_on_scene, :unit_clear, :call_num, :site_id, :user_id, :unit2_os, :unit2_cl, :unit3_os, :unit3_cl, :unit4_os, :unit4_cl)
    end
end
```

**Show Page Code:**

```
  <div class="panel panel-success" id="responding-box">
      <div class="panel-heading"><center><h4>Units Responding</h4></center></div>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><center>Unit #1</center></th>
            <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
            <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><center><%= @call.user.employee_ident %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= @call.unit_on_scene.strftime("%H:%m") %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= @call.unit_clear.strftime("%H:%m") %></center></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><center>Unit #2</center></th>
            <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
            <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><center><%= @call.user.employee_ident %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= @call.unit2_os.strftime("%H:%m") %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= @call.unit2_cl.strftime("%H:%m") %></center></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><center>Unit #3</center></th>
            <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
            <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><center><%= @call.user.employee_ident %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= @call.unit3_os.strftime("%H:%m") %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= @call.unit3_cl.strftime("%H:%m") %></center></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><center>Unit #4</center></th>
            <th><center>Time On Scene</center></th>
            <th><center>Time Clear</center></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><center><%= @call.user.employee_ident %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= @call.unit4_os.strftime("%H:%m") %></center></td>
            <td><center><%= @call.unit4_cl.strftime("%H:%m") %></center></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Rails Console Output:

```
2.2.0 :013 > c = Call.last
  Call Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "calls".* FROM "calls"  ORDER BY "calls"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Call id: 3, call_time: "2015-11-11 09:31:00", status: "ACTIVE", primary_type: "EXPLOSION", secondary_type: "N/A", address: nil, unit_1: "1", unit_2: "2", unit_3: "3", unit_4: "1", call_details: "Reports of explosion at location, proceed with cau...", unit_on_scene: "2000-01-01 09:31:00", unit_clear: "2000-01-01 09:31:00", site_id: 2, created_at: "2015-11-11 09:32:44", updated_at: "2015-11-11 23:08:42", user_id: 1, unit2_os: "2000-01-01 09:57:00", unit2_cl: "2000-01-01 09:57:00", unit3_os: "2000-01-01 09:57:00", unit3_cl: "2000-01-01 09:57:00", unit4_os: "2000-01-01 09:57:00", unit4_cl: "2000-01-01 09:57:00", call_number: 1001>
```

**As you can see it is adding the user_id of employee_idents 4114, 4112, 4113 in the unit_1, 2, 3, and 4 boxes, but all that is being out put is the data from the user_id column in the DB.. is there anyway i can store several user_id's in a single user_id record?**

which will give me the employee_ident of 4114 displaying clearly in the Show, Index pages ect..

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm stumped here..

Comment: Can you show the controller code that is handling the data submission from this form?

Comment: @ReggieB I will edit the post ASAP to include the controller, that may be the issue.

Comment: The controller looks OK. Could you also add the line where for form is declared?

Comment: here is the form_for: <%= form_for(@call) do |f| %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller looks OK - so perhaps its the way the form is set up.

What happens if you change from using the standalone `collection_select` to one called on the form object (f) So instead of:

```
<%= collection_select(:call, :unit_1, User.all, :id, :employee_ident, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %>
```

Try

```
<%= f.collection_select(:unit_1, User.all, :id, :employee_ident, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %>
```

Comment: Ok, so when i add the collect select you provided above it is changing the user_id in the db (confirmed with Rails Console, however when i use  the following in my show page <% @call.user.employee_ident %> is still only pull, across the user_id in the first field.. do i need to adjust this as well some how? (i am knida new at this stuff.. but working to improve.. ill add my show page code above.

Comment: The Answer works for adding the id to the model. ill award best answer to you. Thanks. i have started a new post to address how to access and display the info as it still only saves one of four user_id's NEW POST: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663703/saving-multiple-user-ids-in-a-rails-form-show-index

Comment: @ShawnWilson you seem to have done most of the donkey work yourself, but I'm glad my input was of some help.