# Devise User models and displaying several users in another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using Rails 4 Ruby 2.2. I have 6 users in my app currently.

I want to be able to display up to 4 of those users by referencing them in my Call model. The problem is, that my Call model has the user_id (integer) and only holds one user_id.

**Possible Join Table for Users & Calls**

```
create_join_table :users, :calls do |t|
  t.index :user_id
  t.index :call_id
end
```

In my form I want to be able to select 4 of those users and display them in my Show.html.erb

How can I pull several user_id's from the User model and display them as separate units in Calls?

[How to Reference and Save Several User_ID's to a single form and display said Id's in index / Show Pages of Rails 4 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663703/how-to-reference-and-save-several-user-ids-to-a-single-form-and-display-said-id)

I am at a total loss. I am thinking possibly nested forms or routes but I have no idea where to start and I'm not seeing much when I research the question.

I have the proper associations in the Models, as I can see user_1d "1" in Rails console and in the show.html.erb can link to the unit number with @call.user.employee_ident

So I have created the Join Table (see below)

```
  create_table "calls_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "call_id", null: false
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
  end

  add_index "calls_users", ["call_id", "user_id"], name: "index_calls_users_on_call_id_and_user_id", using: :btree
  add_index "calls_users", ["user_id", "call_id"], name: "index_calls_users_on_user_id_and_call_id", using: :btree
```

The Rails guide really didn't give me much direction to go forward with.

I added this to my User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  #  and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable, :timeoutable

  has_and_belongs_to_many :calls
end
```

And added this to my Calls Model

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base

has_and_belongs_to_many :users

end
```

Add screen shot of the the form layout I currently have to offer further description:

[image]

[image]

Now in the form how do I bring in the units to the form and then display them to the show.html.erb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a [`many-to-many` relationship](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many)...

[image]

Although not documented explicitly in the Rails docs, there are two ways to set this up - [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) & [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

---

For your use case, I'd recommend `has_and_belongs_to_many`. The difference between the two is that `has_many :through` uses a join *model*, allowing you to populate extra attributes that can be used for a range of different things.

[image]

In terms of HABTM, you can do the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :calls
end

#app/models/call.rb
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

You'll have to create a `calls_users` table with the following commands:

```
$ rails g migration CreateCallsUsers

#db/migrate/create_calls_users______.rb
class CreateCallsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table "calls_users", id: false do |t| 
         t.references :call
         t.references :user
      end
   end
end 

$ rake db:migrate
```

You'll then be able to call `@user.calls` / `@call.users` with the data contained in that join table.

--

Now, the important part is to *populate* the join table. To do this, you have [several handy methods](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many):

- `@user.call_ids`
- `@user.calls <<`
- `@user.calls.delete`

The `.call_ids` method can be used as follows:

```
#app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :call_ids, Call.all, :id, :name, multiple: true %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will set the `call_ids` attribute of your `@user` object, which Rails will translate into populating the join model. It will then allow you to call `@user.calls` etc.

-

The other two methods (`<<` & `.delete`) allow you to insert / remove records from the association individually:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
@call = Call.find x

@user.calls << @call
@user.calls.delete @call
```

---

If you want to show the `calls` associated with a `user` in the `users#show` action, you can use the following:

```
#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<% @user.calls.each do |call| %>
   <%= call.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This all makes sense! the only question i have is relating to the form.. the multiple setting to true in the collection select box, while works doesn't quite get to what i am looking for. I have edited my post above to include what i am trying to accomplish is this at all possible to layout the form like this or is this a caviar dream?

Comment: I should also note that I am wanting to add all of this to the Calls MVC not to users. so that being said for the above actions ect do I reverse them? ie @call = Call.find params[:id]

Comment: Disregard last! I got it going.. only running one unit however and then will use an employee model to talk to the other responding units.. the main unit to track is the primary at this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a model called `User` and another model called `Call`, and you want to be able to associate more than one `User` to a `Call`.

If that is correct, then your first problem is that you have the wrong type of relationship (or "association" in a more Rails-like nomenclature). You currently have what Rails calls a `belongs_to` association. Each `Call` "belongs to" one and only one `User`. Your schema does not support associating more that one.

The one that you want is a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association (see Rails docs). In more common data modeling parlance, this is known as a [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship.

What this means is that each `Call` may have zero or more associated `User` records, and each `User` may have zero or more associated `Call` records. This is achieved by means of what is known as a [join table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

Referring back to the Rails doc, they give an example of a corresponding data migration that sets up a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between two models. You will notice that the script includes a `create_table` statement that sets up a join table.

Best of luck.

Comment: I updated the question as im still not getting any results after the join table and associations were updated. could you help further please?